# Getting Eclair on the Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, nook

I would like to do development for a rooted Nook Simple Touch, which uses Eclair. I've downloaded the Android SDK and launched the Virtual Device Manager, but as it is now 2015, it doesn't offer any versions before Gingerbread. Is there a way I can get an Eclair virtual device? Alternatively, is there an older SDK package I can get?

Thank you,
   Bob

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn't offer any versions before Gingerbread

The standalone SDK Manager does when you check the "Obsolete" checkbox. Note that the emulator images were in the "SDK Platform" options back in the old days, rather than having separate line items in the SDK Manager.